# How to get the post order traversal of a BINARY TREE (NOT binary search tree), given only its inorder traversal

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, inorder, postorder

I've given the result of **in-order traversal** of a **binary tree** (not *binary search tree*) as:

**E, D, B, A, G, F, H, C**

Now I've to find out the result of the **post-order** traversal of the same tree for which the *in-order* traversal is given.

Can anyone suggest me any algorithm for this ?

P.S: Is there any way to sketch the tree itself from the *in-order* result ?

Comment: Is there any more data on the tree? Is it a complete tree for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. Your example might represent multiple trees, for example :

```
E                       D
 \                     / \
  D                   E   B
   \                       \
    B                       A
     \                       \
      A                       G                          ...
       \                       \
        G                       F
         \                       \
          F                       G
           \                       \
            H                       C
             \
              C
```

You need at least two orders to reconstruct the tree, and you can only give an order when you have the tree at hand.